# Entity Framework 6 não cria banco de dados

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, orm

Criei um projeto c# WEB MVC5 no visual studio 2013, instalei o entity framework 6 e criei minhas classes("entidades") bem como o DBContext com os respectivos DBsets.

Dentro do WEB.Config eu configurei minha string de conexão e no DBContext eu apontei a string conexão criada. Apesar de ter seguido todos os passos das apostilas que eu li, ao rodar meu projeto web a bendita database não é criada... até initializer eu criei.

Servidor, Usuario e senha do servidor de banco estão corretos... nao consigo achar uma unica brecha pro código não funcionar!

Classes...

**Nivel_Acesso**

```
    public class Nivel_Acesso
    {
     public int Nivel_AcessoID { get; set; }
     public String Nivel { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Acesso> Acesso { get; set; }
    }
```

**Acesso**

```
    public class Acesso
    {
      public int AcessoID { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("Nivel_AcessoID")]
      public int Nivel_AcessoID { get; set; }
      public String Usuario { get; set; }
      public String Senha { get; set; }        
    }
```

**ClinicaDBContext**

```
    public class ClinicaDBContext : DbContext 
    {
    public ClinicaDBContext() : base("Conexao"){}
        public DbSet<Nivel_Acesso> Nivel_Acesso { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Acesso> Acesso { get; set; }

    }
```

**Web.config**

```
      <connectionStrings>
       <add name="Conexao" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="Server=.;Database=Clinica;User Id=sa;" />
       </connectionStrings>
```

Meu servidor não possui senha!

Para quem deseja verificar o código por inteiro, disponibilizo o link do projeto:

http://www.4shared.com/rar/L3lsmYrvce/SistemaC.html

Comment: Cara sua string de conexão é gerada automaticamente, ele não está gereando seu EDMX?

Comment: Gerada automaticamente? não sabia disto e até mesmo sobre o EDMX eu nao tinha conhecimento. Li uma série de apostilas e nenhuma delas citava o EDMX, agora que você falou eu dei uma pesquisada e descobri do que se trata, entretanto se o .edmx fica listado na estrutura de diretórios, ele não foi criado.

Comment: esse tutorial é muito bom, segue o passo a passo que você irá conseguir criar.
http://www.macoratti.net/11/09/ef4_mp1.htm

Comment: ele é gerado sim na estruturada de diretórios.
ele te mostra o modelo do banco.
bem como seus objetos gerados através de suas tabelas.

Comment: Pelo que estou vendo, o .edmx é criado a partir de uma base ja existente... mas no meu caso, o intuito é gerar uma base a partir de minhas entidades criadas.

Comment: Entendi você está fazendo o caminho inverso? mais porque isso?

Comment: Ué... porque o grande atrativo da ORM é justamente esse, não se preocupar em codificar SQL e se ausentar da necessidade de construir estruturas do banco dentro do servidor.

Comment: Cleiton, tente fazer da seguinte maneira. Se funcionar eu coloco em resposta: Na sua *connection string* ao invés de colocar esse nome "Conexão", coloque o nome do seu *DbContext*, ou seja, "ClinicaDBContext". Só pra ver se funciona. E veja depois, pois a sua *string* de conexão realmente é gerada automaticamente !

Comment: Eu ja havia tentado isso e tambem não funcionou... tentei novamente e tambem não deu resultado algum.

Comment: Adicionei o link de download do projeto.

Comment: Cleiton eu abri seu projeto e vi que falta muita coisa, e também da forma que está sendo feita não vai criar o banco de dados de acordo com suas classes. Encontrei um bom tutorial que pode te ajudar, no qual ensina desde de o começo do projeto.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Falta o que por exemplo? Ja tenho as classes de modelo, ja tenho o WebConfig configurado e com string de conexao, ja tenho a classe DBContext com os devidos dbsets, ja tenho um controler que oferece acesso a minha view principal... Eu ja havia consultado essa página, mas não encontrei nenhuma discrepancia.

Comment: Cleiton uma dica pra você que aprendendo: [vá no site oficial](http://asp.net/mvc) e faça o *getting started*... É melhor fazer desde o princípio. Lá com toda certeza, vai te ajudar a achar seu erro.

Comment: Vou baixar seu código aqui e já respondo. Você não prefere usar um GitHub ou algo que fique mais fácil a galera sugerir modificação no seu código?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, sua solução está desatualizada. É preciso uma atualização de todos os pacotes da solução. Abra o *Package Manager Console* e digite o seguinte:

> PM> Update-Package

Houve algum problema esquisito com seus pacotes, então tive que excluir o diretório `packages` da solução e criar de novo através do mesmo comando. Pode ser necessário fechar e reabrir a solução pro que vem a seguir.

O *Code First* não está habilitado no projeto. Significa que não há suporte a *Migrations* (migrações incrementais de banco), nem a controle de modificações de contexto. Abra o *Package Manager Console* e digite o seguinte:

> PM> Enable-Migrations

A criação da configuração pegou este erro:

> The property 'Nivel_AcessoID' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type.

Significa que você configurou uma ID errado, ou seja, um parâmetro real em banco, e o Entity Framework entendeu o ID como uma propriedade de navegação, que é apenas uma propriedade a mais para carregar outras informações de entidades relacionadas. Precisei alterar o seguinte:

```
namespace SistemaC.Models
{
    public class Acesso
    {
        [Key]
        public int AcessoId { get; set; }
        public int NivelAcessoId { get; set; } // Isto é uma informação de banco.

        [Required]
        public String Usuario { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public String Senha { get; set; }

        public virtual NivelAcesso NivelAcesso { get; set; } // Isto é um atributo de navegação.
    }
}
```

Repare que tirei `[ForeignKey("Nivel_AcessoID")]`. Ele serve para propriedades de navegação, e não para propriedades chave. Como seu projeto é muito simples, o Entity Framework sabe identificar sozinho e pela nomenclatura as propriedades de navegação. Você pode, portanto, não usar o atributo.

Da mesma forma, alterei `NivelAcesso`:

```
namespace SistemaC.Models
{
    public class NivelAcesso
    {
        [Key]
        public int NivelAcessoId { get; set; }
        public String Nivel { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Acesso> Acessos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A conveção de nomes não usa "_" nos nomes dos objetos. Outra coisa que precisei fazer é identificar qual é a chave do *Model* com o atributo `[Key]`.

`ICollections` relacionadas são sempre com nomes no plural, pra que você saiba durante a programação que está lidando com uma coleção, e não com um objeto somente.

O contexto ficou assim:

```
namespace SistemaC.Models
{
    public class ClinicaDbContext : DbContext 
    {
        //public ClinicaDBContext()
        //{
        //    Database.SetInitializer<ClinicaDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ClinicaDBContext>());
        //}
            public DbSet<NivelAcesso> NivelAcessos { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Acesso> Acessos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Tudo também no plural.

Precisei apagar o `DBInit.cs`. Ele estava totalmente errado. O `Global.asax` ficou assim:

```
namespace SistemaC
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Corrigido isso, consegui gerar a primeira *Migration* aquela que instala o banco de dados de fato, assim:

> PM> Add-Migration Inicial

Gerou:

```
namespace SistemaC.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class Inicial : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Acessoes",
                c => new
                    {
                        AcessoId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        NivelAcessoId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Usuario = c.String(nullable: false),
                        Senha = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.AcessoId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.NivelAcessoes", t => t.NivelAcessoId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.NivelAcessoId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.NivelAcessoes",
                c => new
                    {
                        NivelAcessoId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Nivel = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.NivelAcessoId);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Acessoes", "NivelAcessoId", "dbo.NivelAcessoes");
            DropIndex("dbo.Acessoes", new[] { "NivelAcessoId" });
            DropTable("dbo.NivelAcessoes");
            DropTable("dbo.Acessoes");
        }
    }
}
```

"Cigano, o nome da tabela é **Acessos**, não **Acessoes**, e **NiveisAcessos**, não **NivelAcessoes**". Tudo bem. A pluralização do Entity Framework é em inglês. Por isso o nome. Podemos arrumar da seguinte forma:

```
namespace SistemaC.Models
{
    [Table("Acessos")]
    public class Acesso
    { ... }
}

namespace SistemaC.Models
{
    [Table("NiveisAcessos")]
    public class NivelAcesso
    { ... }
}
```

Resultado:

```
namespace SistemaC.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class Initial : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Acessos",
                c => new
                    {
                        AcessoId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        NivelAcessoId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Usuario = c.String(nullable: false),
                        Senha = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.AcessoId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.NiveisAcessos", t => t.NivelAcessoId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.NivelAcessoId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.NiveisAcessos",
                c => new
                    {
                        NivelAcessoId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Nivel = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.NivelAcessoId);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Acessos", "NivelAcessoId", "dbo.NiveisAcessos");
            DropIndex("dbo.Acessos", new[] { "NivelAcessoId" });
            DropTable("dbo.NiveisAcessos");
            DropTable("dbo.Acessos");
        }
    }
}
```

Por fim, atualize a base com o comando:

> PM> Update-Database

O banco será criado com as tabelas, de acordo com a origem apontada na sua `Connection String`. Aliás, precisei alterar ela levemente para permitir autenticação com o Windows e eu não precisar usar o usuário `sa`:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ClinicaDBContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Clinica;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Feito isso, compilou com banco e tudo. [Você pode baixar os fontes aqui](https://github.com/cigano/SistemaCleitonRibeiro).

Answer (score 4):

no construtor da sua classe DBContext tente adicionar a seguinte instrução de código.

```
public class ClinicaDBContext : DbContext 
{
   public ClinicaDBContext() : base("Conexao")
   {
      Database.SetInitializer<ClinicaDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ClinicaDBContext>());
   }     

   public DbSet<Nivel_Acesso> Nivel_Acesso { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Acesso> Acesso { get; set; }
}
```

Verifique também se dentro do seu arquivo Web.config tem a instrução de inicialização da classe, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<entityFramework>
  <contexts>
    <context type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext, ContosoUniversity">
      <databaseInitializer type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolInitializer, ContosoUniversity" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: hmm... :/ infelizmente não funcionou... eu adicionei a instrução, salvei e dei build. Tentei rodar o projeto, mas o servidor continua sem o banco clinica.

Comment: Amigo, coloque um breakpoint no código que lhe passei, dentro do construtor e veja se na execução do projeto o trecho de código vai ser executado.

Comment: Ao que parece, ele nem chega a entrar na classe ClinicaDBContext.

Comment: Essa classe tem que ser instanciada se não seu banco de dados não será criado. O tutorial que você está seguindo é online? Caso seja, pode me passar para que eu possa te ajudar melhor?

Comment: Eu baixei uma apostila da K19 e acessei o material do curso de um amigo, em nenhum desses materiais existe a instrução que onde instanciar e chamar o context. Eu segui o passo a passo e em nenhum tuto da internet eu vi a context sendo instanciada. http://www.k19.com.br/cursos/desenvolvimento-web-com-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Eu fiz uns testes aqui e encontrei uma coisa que pode estar faltando no seu código. Verifique se dentro do Web.config tem a instrução para inicializar a classe. Vou editar a resposta adicionando um exemplo.

Comment: Não de certo Ton :/ mas obrigado