# Relacionamentos Apenas no EDMX afeta performance?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, relacionamento

Tenho uma dúvida a respeito do Entity Framework.

Aqui na empresa onde eu trabalho, as tabelas são geradas no banco sem nenhum relacionamento, até são criados os campos que irão ser chaves estrangeiras mas,
todo o relacionamento é feito pelo EDMX no Entity Framework.

A versão que acabamos de migrar é a 5 e o banco de dados é o MySQL.

Pelo que eu li, o MySQL cria os index mas para isso ele precisa das FK, e como nós apenas criamos as tabelas sem relacionar nada, creio que isso venha a tornar o sistema mais pesado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já está **muito** errado o jeito que vocês usam. Entity Framework sem chaves estrangeiras **não faz qualquer sentido sob qualquer ponto de vista**.

Respondendo sua pergunta, **sim, e muito**.

Não havendo chaves estrangeiras, não há índices. Não havendo índices, o plano de execução vai usar [`TABLE SCANS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html) para buscar a informação, e a performance será um desastre, sobretudo considerando *Lazy Load* (carga preguiçosa), que é uma das tônicas do Entity Framework.

O modo de trabalho com o Entity Framework supõe relacionamentos **especificados no *Model***, e é daqui que se extrai as informações sobre tabelas, suas chaves privadas e estrangeiras.

É importante dizer que o modelo EDMX é defasado e deve ser descontinuado assim que possível. O recomendado é o uso de *Migrations*. [Nesta resposta executo um roteiro completo de configuração, considerando que todos os seus *Models* foram retirados do EDMX e convertidos em classes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41902/entity-framework-6-n%C3%A3o-cria-banco-de-dados/42204#42204). Para separar as classes, [use este artigo](http://nullablecode.com/2013/09/splitting-entity-framework-model-classes-separate-projects/).

Comment: Muito obrigado. Me ajudou muito a sua reposta!