# Como conectar ao Banco de Dados do Azure?

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-azure

Bem amigos, tenho um banco de dados no Azure, mas não consigo me conectar a ele. O erro é que meu IP não está autorizado a realizar tal conexão, o que eu fiz foi adicionar uma nova regra ao firewall do servidor do banco, mas cada momento que mudo de IP tenho esse problema. O que devo fazer para resolver de vez com esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Faça o login na Azure;
- Na parte de bancos de dados, escolha o banco de dados desejado;
- Escolha a opção "Gerenciar";
- O Azure dirá que precisa adicionar uma exceção no Firewall para o seu IP e pede uma confirmação. Confirme;
- A próxima tela perguntará se você quer usar o editor online para acessar o banco. A partir deste momento, o banco já poderá ser acessado até mesmo pelo seu SQL Server Management Studio local.

Sobre sempre pedir a cada mudança de IP, é uma característica de segurança do serviço Azure. Só seria possível fixar um IP no seu banco de dados se ele estivesse hospedado dentro de uma máquina virtual, por exemplo, sem esta configuração de *endpoints*, que é obrigatória no caso de hospedagem de banco de dados.

Comment: Bem meu amigo, muito obrigado pela resposta, mas o problema é que cada momento que mudo de IP preciso colocar uma exceção no Firewall.

Comment: Sim, é assim mesmo que funciona.

Comment: Opa, então eu poderia criar uma VM e criar o BD lá dendro, mas como eu faria acesso aos recursos dessa VM através de uma aplicação Asp.Net MVC por exemplo, como usaria o Entity Framwork?

Comment: Igual ao que você usa hoje. A diferença é que não viria tudo configurado pra você. Você teria que aprender a configurar o IIS, o Web Deploy, e assim por diante. É um caminho um pouco comprido, mas que vale a pena.

Comment: Bem @Cigano Morrison Mendez se eu continuar usando o Banco de Dados como está sem a VM, ao criar um Web Application Asp.Net MVC eu não conseguiria disponibiliza-lo pois o Firewall bloquearia todos os acessos, correto? Nesse caso, qual seria a alternativa?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Errado. O Firewall bloqueia apenas **acessos externos**. Acessos feitos dentro do mesmo ambiente de nuvem são livres.

Comment: Só pra confirmar... Então quer dizer que se eu criar um Web Application e publicar no Azure, não terei problemas com o acesso ao banco de dados?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues De forma alguma. A troca de informações entre os componentes deve ocorrer livremente. Apenas o acesso externo é regrado (e com razão) para se evitar problemas de segurança.

Comment: então todo momento em que eu quiser atualizar algo no banco, criar tabelas manualmente terei que criar uma nova regra no firewall caso o meu IP seja diferente correto?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Aparentemente você não está usando o conceito de *Migrations*, em que o Web Deploy realiza todas as alterações de banco pra você. [Ensino a configurar esta parte nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41902/entity-framework-6-n%C3%A3o-cria-banco-de-dados/42204#42204).